# All Activities closed, 5 threads remain

Tags: android, multithreading

Despite knowing that I shouldn't have a close application button I still do. After all my activities are done, I call the finish() method and they call destructors and everything. The behavior for the user is also correct. But I'd like to know why are there still 5 open threads:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Running) 
Thread [<12> Binder_3] (Running)    
Thread [<11> android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorThread] (Running)   
Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

Is it caused by a leak or is it normal Android behavior?

Answer (score 2):

**main** and **Binder_n** threads are standart android application threads, and they will be killed by system. It is not you problem (actually it is not a problem at all).

I suppose you create **SensorThread** - and you should stop it. If you start it in `onCreate` of activity - you should stop it in `onDestroy`.

Comment: I think it's a leak from one of the many listeners I have. Is there a way of dbugging/finding out which one it is? Could it be a button one?

Comment: It can not be "button click listener" - it is thread that read sensors state. Check you code for methods `SensorManager.registerListener()`. For each listener you should call `SensorManager.unregisterListener()`

Comment: I only have several onClickListeners for buttons and dialogs. This Activity doesn't have the Location and Battery listeners.

Comment: It's being created by EditField.requestFocus(), weird.

Comment: I suppose it can be soft keyboard issue, so - you have not care about it.